# How to replace all BOOST_FOREACH with C++11 for in visual studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, boost, refactoring

I have an old codebase that uses Boost agressively. I migrated it to vs2012. Now I want to make code more readable and modern. I wonder how to replace all `BOOST_FOREACH` with C++11 `for` in visual studio 2012?

I would love to have a regular expression that would work with VS find\replace.

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of "automatic" refactoring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple VS Find and Replace regex you can start with is:

```
Find what: BOOST_FOREACH\((.+), (.+)\)
Replace with: for($1 : $2)
```

check Use Regular Expressions

Answer (score -1):

Just redefine it and you'll preserve compatibility with C++03 as a bonus. 
Assuming youve `#define foreach BOOST_FOREACH`, just redefine:

```
#define foreach(value, container) for(value : container)
```

Comment: This does not change any existing code and won't make it more readable.